# How to make more than one event on a button

Tags: android

How can I make two events on the same button? In 1st click open an Activity A, the 2nd click opens another Activity B

How can I make for example:

1st Click the button he opened a Activity

2nd Click it opens another Activity

Example:

```
public void checkButton(View view) {

if 1st click{

open.ActivityA();

}

if 2nd click{

open.ActivityB();     

      }
   }
}
```

Best regards,

Comment: Store a value in SharedPrefs would probably be the simplest way. It could be 1/2, ActivityToOpen, anything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private boolean mFirstClick = true;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mFirstClick) {
                startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityA.class));
                mFirstClick = false;
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityB.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

You may need to persist mFirstClick if this is in an Activity or Fragment that is destroyed when starting activity A or B.

Comment: If you need more than a boolean state, use an int instead of boolean and keep track of the value, increasing on each click.